# Modify multiple delete queries into as little update queries as possible?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-optimization

We currently have this code snippet:

```
$this->db->where('id', $id)->delete($this->table);
$this->db->where('product_id', $id)->delete($this->clink);
$this->db->where('product_id', $id)->delete($this->tlink);

$variants = $this->db->select('id')->from($this->vlink)->where('product_id', $id)->get();
if ($variants->num_rows() !== 0) {

    //turns array(array('id' => 1), array('id' => 2)) into array(1,2)
    $variants = $variants->result_array();
    foreach ($variants as &$v) {
        $v = $v['id'];
    }

    $this->db->where('product_id', $id)->delete($this->vlink);
    $this->db->where_in('variant_id', $variants)->delete('cart_variant_values');
    $this->db->where_in('variant_id', $variants)->delete('cart_variant_images');
    $this->db->where_in('variant_id', $variants)->delete('cart_variant_documents');
}
```

Which translates into this:

```
delete from $this->table where id = $id
delete from $this->clink where product_id = $id
delete from $this->tlink where product_id = $id

$variants = select id from $this->vlink where product_id = $id //e.g. (1,2) 

delete from $this->vlink where product_id = $id
delete from cart_variant_values where variant_id in $variants
delete from cart_variant_images where variant_id in $variants
delete from cart_variant_documents where variant_id in $variants
```

Now I need to modify the code so instead of deleting all the rows, it sets the `end_date` column on them all.

I know I could just modify it. leaving it with the same amount of queries, but I was hoping that being an update instead of a delete I could shrink this down into less queries?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the number of delete queries you can use Multiple-table delete queries, by which you can reduce it to a single query
[DELETE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

You can implement multiple table queries in `UPDATE` too
[UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)